# why does $http service consume full url of rest service and $resource doesn't?

Tags: angularjs, ajax, rest

This is my service:

```
app.factory("ResourceService", function ($resource, $q, $http) {
return {
    getAll: function () {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $http.get('https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/list/all').then(function (response) {
            deferred.resolve(response);
        }, function (error) {
            deferred.reject(error);
        });
        return deferred.promise;
    },
    allUsingResource: function () {
        return $resource('https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/list/all');
    }
}
});
```

This is my controller:

```
app.controller("Controller", function ($scope, ResourceService) {
function getAll() {
    ResourceService.getAll().then(function (response) {
        $scope.all = response.data;
    }, function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
}
function runAll() {
    var data = ResourceService.allUsingResource();
    data.query(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    }, function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
}
runAll();
getAll();
});
```

While everything goes swell with $http, i get badcfg with $resource:

Error: [$resource:badcfg] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.5/$resource/badcfg?p0=query&p1=array&p2=object&p3=GET&p4=https%3A%2F%2Fdog.ceo%2Fapi%2Fbreeds%2Flist%2Fall

What am I missing?

Comment: What data structure you get with: https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/list/all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run `data.query` on `$resource` object by default it expects [array in response](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource):

```
 'query':  {method:'GET', isArray:true},
```

So be sure you return an array and not an object from `https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/list/all`

---

Read error from URL Angularjs Provided for you:

https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$resource/badcfg?p0=query&p1=array&p2=object&p3=GET&p4=https:%2F%2Fdog.ceo%2Fapi%2Fbreeds%2Flist%2Fall

> Error in resource configuration for action `query`. Expected response to contain an array but got an object (Request: GET https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/list/all)
>
> #### Description
>
> This error occurs when the $resource service expects a response that can be deserialized as an array but receives an object, or vice versa. By default, all resource actions expect objects, except query which expects arrays.
>
> To resolve this error, make sure your $resource configuration matches the actual format of the data returned from the server.
>
> For more information, see the [$resource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) API reference documentation.

Comment: that's why it didn't work. works fine with an array json. many thanks